# Double Click 1x1 Tracking Pixel

Tags: google-analytics, pixel

I run a wordpress blog with Google analytics, but without any Doubleclick products. Still, I see this pixel being fired off every time on pageload.

```
https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=3&tid=UA-85285147-1&cid=892804452.1516281915&jid=348589784&_gid=1186973785.1516281915&gjid=608593715&_v=j66&z=1313374698
```

Can anyone tell me if it is related to Analystics and if I can get rid of it?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably activated "Remarketing and Advertising Reporting Features" in Analytics. Since this is based on data from the Google Advertising network it redirects GA tracking calls via Doubleclick, so that is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested using Web Page Test (https://www.webpagetest.org/result/180118_4C_087f3f76144e177e37f483d34f918943/1/breakdown/) where you can see a list of the requests and there is no Double Click tags firing.

It's either Google Analytics with Display features or a Wordpress Plugin firing the DoubleClick pixel. It could be wordpress itself using Jetpack